How can I create a U-turn for routes in OSM?
I am facing a problem when mapping a route in which the bus should make a U-turn at Rua A (Recanto dos Lagos) at coordinates 21°42'34.6"S 43°19'49.7"W, but the route follows another street (Rua Amaryllis) instead of returning. I tried adding a mini roundabout to the location, but that didn't solve the problem. Is there another way to try to make this return?
Region
https://www.openstreetmap.org/edit#map=19/-21.70959/-43.33005
Route
https://map.project-osrm.org/?z=13&center=-21.711323%2C-43.347865&loc=-21.663214%2C-43.334396&loc=-21.668785%2C-43.336342&loc=-21.671472%2C-43.337615&loc=-21.678192%2C-43.344787&loc=-21.683990%2C-43.347309&loc=-21.685440%2C-43.348237&loc=-21.686009%2C-43.348526&loc=-21.690022%2C-43.349377&loc=-21.691780%2C-43.351082&loc=-21.694256%2C-43.353470&loc=-21.695539%2C-43.355267&loc=-21.697735%2C-43.356979&loc=-21.698774%2C-43.357468&loc=-21.702345%2C-43.358765&loc=-21.703428%2C-43.345413&loc=-21.703979%2C-43.343754&loc=-21.704433%2C-43.341866&loc=-21.706444%2C-43.341793&loc=-21.708149%2C-43.340984&loc=-21.712643%2C-43.338207&loc=-21.713966%2C-43.336380&loc=-21.711660%2C-43.336376&loc=-21.704533%2C-43.339779&loc=-21.704044%2C-4

Please don't add features that don't exist in reality. If there is no mini-roundabout, then don't add one to OSM. If the router has a bug, then contact the developers of the routing engine.

Is there another way to try to make this return?

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. If this is an official bus route then you can add this to OSM via a public transport relation: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buses. Telling the router instead to make a u-turn at a specific intersection is probably not possible. Buses rarely perform u-turns and the router will try to find a more feasible / more realistic loop to perform.
